# Oracle Linux Server to SCP: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: oraclelinux

Transferring the files between Oracle DB server to the SCP(Scientific Computing Platform) Server
but got the below error.

```
**Unexpected error occurred:
  ORA-20001: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at storedProcs.FileUtils.sftp_get(FileUtils.java:224)
  ORA-06512: at "Packagename.Procedurename", line 525**
```

Transfer the files between Oracle Linux server to SCP server

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Transferring the files between a server to another server required the JSCH jar for connecting the servers.
Therefore, When we are transferring the files between Oracle DB server to
SCP server. We need to configure the Oracle JSCH jar in SSH Server configuration.

The issue was because of Oracle jsch lib, The SCP team guess uses very old cipher algorithm in order to connect. So The SCP team has just added several of those algorithms to our ssh server configuration.

Then It starts working as we expected.